# R Plotly - Bars overlap to other xaxis ticks

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization

**Problem:** How can I prevent plotly from "overlaying" the bars to other xaxis ticks? Note I want to keep all factor levels and just show no bar if the factor level is not in the data (so `droplevels()` won't give the desired output).

Many thanks for suggestions!!

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

dt <- data.table(
  x = c("a", "b"),
  y = c(10, 10)
)

dt[, x := factor(x, levels = c("b", "c", "d", "a"))]

plot_ly(dt, x = ~x) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just adding `width=1`:

```
plot_ly(dt, x = ~x) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~y, width=1)
```